# Why are format codes "%-m" and "%-d" not working when parsing dates using the datetime module?

Tags: python, list, sorting, datetime

```
my_dates = [['y', 'd', 't', 'd', '2/1/2021', ''],
            ['v', 'd', 't', 't', '7/2/2020', ''],
            ['v', 'd', 't', 't', '10/1/2020', ''],
            ['d', 't', 't', 't', '12/1/2023', '']]

my_dates.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date[4], "%-m/%-d/%y"))
print(my_dates)
```

I am trying to sort the dates in my list of lists from oldest to newest using a lambda function.

I was reading the documentation here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime. It stated

> `%-m` Month as a decimal number. 1, 2, ..., 12

and

> `%m` Month as a zero-padded decimal number. 01, 02, ..., 12

but I am getting this error:

```
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib_strptime.py", line 341, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("'%s' is a bad directive in format '%s'" %
ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%-m/%-d/%y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information that is shown on the page you were reading is incorrect.

If you are in doubt, you should always refer to the **official Python documentation** at https://docs.python.org.

The documentation of the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) module lists all the valid format codes for `strptime`.

In your case you need `%m/%d/%Y`:

> `%m` Month as a zero-padded decimal number. (9)

> `%d` Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number. (9)

> `%Y` Year with century as a decimal number.

Importantly, refer to the [note (9)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) at the bottom of the page:

> 9. When used with the `strptime()` method, the leading zero is optional for formats `%d`, `%m`, [...]

This means that `%m` is used to parse the month *both* from a zero-padded decimal number (01, 02, ..., 12) *and* from a non-zero-padded decimal number (1, 2, ..., 12).